# Python dependencies error when installing python-dev and python-pip

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, apt

When trying to install MHN, I get this error. I have Python2 and python-pip installed. Any thoughts?

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-dev : Depends: python (= 2.7.15~rc1-1)
              Depends: libpython-dev (= 2.7.15~rc1-1) but it is not going to be installed
 python-pip : Depends: python-pip-whl (= 9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.3) but 20.0.2-5ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
              Recommends: python-all-dev (>= 2.6) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: python-setuptools but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: python-wheel but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried purging python2 so far, anything more because I don't find anything on the net. Thanks

Comment: why r u using python 2.7 ?? its no more supported

Comment: is the depencies needed by MHN

Comment: so you have conflict coz Ubuntu comes with an installed python3. you need to isolate py2. 7 in venv and install MHN in it

Comment: yes, more or less